# Get notification when file added to File Share

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

Is there a way to get notified when a new file is added/modified to Azure File Share?

Similar feature exists with AWS S3 where one can configure an S3 bucket to send message to SQS or SNS or Lambda (or other) when a new File is added.

An alternative (though less preferred) is to be able to query files in a share such that only modified/new files after date X will be returned.

Comment: As of today this feature does not exist. It does for Blob Storage though (which is equivalent to S3). Will that work for you?

Comment: @Guarav Mantri it would solve half my issue. I'm trying to bring various Azure logs, and as some are written to Blobs, some are also written to Shares (I might be mistaken though)

Comment: Please see this two links if working with Blob Storage is OK with you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview. HTH.

Comment: This is helpful. I could use this to implement a Function that will push events to a Queue, which at later time will be polled.
(Webhooks are not an option for our deployment type).
It really is a shame they didn't add an option to send these notifications to a Storage Account's Queue.
Also, any idea when this will be generally available (in other regions, out of preview)?

Comment: `Also, any idea when this will be generally available (in other regions, out of preview)?` - If your question is about Azure Event Grids, please ask a question about the roadmap here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview.

Comment: Thank you! I will.
Can you post the comment with the 2 links as answer? I'd like to mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting notifications on addition/modification of blobs (not files), you have multiple options available:

1. **Azure Functions (w/ Blob Storage Binding)**: In this scenario, a function will get invoked when a blob is added or updated. More details about this can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob.
2. **Azure Event Grid (w/ Blob Integration)**: Currently (at the time of providing this answer), this service is in preview and has limited availability in terms of regions. Currently it only supports `Blob Creation` (and not blob updation) event. More information about this can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview.

Comment: It should be pointed out that Microsoft storage logs are created on a "best effort" basis - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/About-Storage-Analytics-Logging
Thus events CAN BE OMITTED!