# Is there any way to know when new file gets in azure file storage

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-files

I am trying to download and perform some action whenever there is new file in file storage.

but there is absolutely no way to do it.

I tried mapping the drive on to a vm and use Inotifywait tool (failed to get notifications).

I tried logic app and sftp to file share was not able to connect it.

I checking all over internet but found nothing

can anyone suggest any alternative ?

Thanks

Comment: As of today, this feature does not exist. It does for Blob Storage. You may refer to the similar discussion done on [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676541/get-notification-when-file-added-to-file-share).

Comment: Apparently for file storage you have to write your own trigger using the SDK. I am surprised no one hasn't done this already and made it a nuget extension

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to download and perform some action whenever there is new file in file storage.

As far as I know, it is not supported Azure storage file trigger now. I also find the related [azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/20324680-add-trigger-for-azure-file-storage).

> can anyone suggest any alternative?

Based on my experience, if azure blob storage is possible, you could use blob trigger to replace it. Or you could use WebJob time trigger to check whether there is any update on the storage file share.